# Who creates the Threads? Programmer, OS, Compiler OR Programming Language?

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading

who is the first and main creator of threads?
if a programming language does not support threads, can we run multithreading on it?
if an OS does not support threads, can we run multithreading on it?

Comment: I think you should narrow this question down to a particular implementation -- the answers to your questions will vary from one OS to another, so without being specific, the only accurate answer would be "it depends".

Comment: for example in Windows what is the answer

Comment: All modern versions of Windows support multithreading, so when a programming language's API wants to create a new thread, it calls down to a Windows API function (e.g. `_beginthreadex()`) and that call handles the creation a new thread via Windows' scheduler.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner you mean `CreateThread` or `pthread_create`

Comment: `_beginthreadex()` and `CreateThread()` are both commonly used under Windows; `pthread_create()` is not part of the Windows API (unless Microsoft added it recently and didn't tell me ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lets look at definations: Kernel-Level and User-Level threads; cs.iit.edu](http://www.cs.iit.edu/%7Ecs561/cs450/ChilkuriDineshThreads/dinesh%27s%20files/User%20and%20Kernel%20Level%20Threads.html)

> User-Level Threads
>
> Kernel-Level threads make concurrency much cheaper than process
> because, much less state to allocate and initialize. However, for
> fine-grained concurrency, kernel-level threads still suffer from too
> much overhead. Thread operations still require system calls. Ideally,
> we require thread operations to be as fast as a procedure call.
> Kernel-Level threads have to be general to support the needs of all
> programmers, languages, runtimes, etc. For such fine grained
> concurrency we need still "cheaper" threads.
>
> To make threads cheap and fast, they need to be implemented at user
> level. User-Level threads are managed entirely by the run-time system
> (user-level library).The kernel knows nothing about user-level threads
> and manages them as if they were single-threaded processes.User-Level
> threads are small and fast, each thread is represented by a
> PC,register,stack, and small thread control block. Creating a new
> thread, switiching between threads, and synchronizing threads are done
> via procedure call. i.e no kernel involvement. User-Level threads are
> hundred times faster than Kernel-Level threads.

An advantage of user-level threads is:

> The most obvious advantage of this technique is that a user-level
> threads package can be implemented on an Operating System that does
> not support threads.

So if programming language supports multithreading, programmer can make thread on even run it on single-thread OS.

Answer (score 1):

> who is the first and main creator of threads?

The operating system

> if a programming language doest not support threads, can we run multitreading on it?

It depends. If that programing language supports any native binding (like JNI/PINVOKE/Node.js addons), you can create threads in that native level and marshal your programing language code into the native threads.

It could be an incomplete solution, because threading also involves memory barriers, memory ordering, happens-before, shared data and so on, you will need to handle all of those by yourself.

> if an OS doest not support threads, can we run multitreading on it?

If your OS doesn't support multithreading, than nothing can really fill that void. you can imitate multithreading by letting your compiler insert safe-points in your code and every time your program reaches a safe-point, the application scheduler might halt the current code execution and switch execution to another psuedo-thread. In a nutshell we call such solution "A fiber" or "A green thread".

Quit funnily, that's what the early versions of Java did, hoping they could beat the OS scheduler by writing their own, better scheduler, before understanding that they are not any better the Windows/Linux kernel development team.

Comment: _It could be an incomplete solution, because threading also involves memory barriers, memory ordering, happens-before, shared data and so on, you will need to handle all of those by yourself._  -- for some language implementations it may not work at all. Consider old Visual Basic that relies on its thread-unsafe run-time library while executing every statement.